# c# Как программно задать режим масштабирования высокого разрешения

Tags: c#, реестр

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно программно нажать на эту галочку и установить в combobox "Приложение".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете нашёл следующий вариант:

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers", Environment.CurrentDirectory, "WINXPSP3");
```

Но он, к сожалению, ничего не делает. Есть ли ещё какие-то варианты?

P.S. Проблема в том, что я делаю программу на ноутбуке. Открывать её нужно на компьютере. Нашёл вот такое простейшее решение, чтобы программа никуда "не уползала" и интерфейс не уходил в космос

Comment: Работать с реестром надо из x64 приложения. Если у вас Any CPU, пересоберите под x64.

Comment: Изменил на x64. В реестр запись добавляется, но "галочка" не ставится на режиме масштабирования. Честно - не уверен, что именно этот параметр в реестре позволит установить её...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взято с сайта: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Добавляем в app.manifest строчки:

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
        <!-- Windows 10 compatibility -->
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
    </application>
</compatibility>
```

Добавляем в App.config строчки:

```
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
    <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
```

Должно выглядеть это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]