# Адаптация Windows Forms под разный масштаб

Tags: c#, windows, .net, winforms

Написал небольшую программку на WinForms, но столкнулся с тем что при запуске на масштабе Windows 100% программа выглядит адекватно и хорошо, а при 125% съезжает. Не нашёл внятного ответа как адаптировать это. Dock делает всё только хуже, пробовал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Версия дотнета какая? Но по сути проблема в том, что вы используете пиксельоое позиционирование контролов, а надо использовать панели.

Comment: Пробовали использовать TableLayoutPanel, размещать в его ячейках контролы с DockStyleFill и задавать размеры строк и столбцов в процентах? WinForms плохо дружит с изменением dpi "на лету", однозначно нужно использовать контейнеры, которые позволяют автоматическое выравнивание или задание размеров в процентах от размера клиентской области окна, без них все так и будет плыть. Альтернатива только получать актуальное значение dpi каким либо образом и применять корректировки к положению и размерам контролов вручную, но я уверен что вы этого не хотите

Comment: @aepot Версия 5.0, только начинаю своё знакомство с WinForms, не знал что можно использовать панели. Благодарю за подсказку

Comment: Раньше сталкивался с проблемой масштабирования. Попробуй вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1297877/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f